# Como importar arquivo para sistema Ruby on Rails sem receber o erro "No sunch file or directory @ rb_sysopen - arquivo.txt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload

O meu programa lê um arquivo .txt por exemplo, itera sobre as informações internas e armazenar no banco de dados.

Mas na hora que o arquivo é enviado ele da um erro dizendo que não conhece o caminho do arquivo... Na minha compreensão, quando o arquivo era enviado ele ficava armazenado na variável que é especificada, mas tudo bem.

O erro é mostrado na imagem anexada. Percebe-se que a linha apontada é justamente onde será aberto o arquivo que não é encontrado.

**Controller**

```
def import

  errors = []
  file = params['file']
  File.open(file).each do |line|
  begin
    line = line.split("\t")

    next if line[0] == "Comprador"

    buyer = line[0] rescue row[0]
    description = line[1] rescue line[1] 
    unity_price = line[2].to_f rescue line[2].to_f
    quantiti = line[3].to_i rescue line[3] .to_i
    address = line[4] rescue line[4] 
    provider = line[5] rescue line[5] 
    total_gross = "Total: #{(unity_price * quantiti).round(2)}"

    Record.create(buyer: buyer, description: description, unity_price: unity_price,  quantiti: quantiti,  address: address,  provider: provider)
  rescue Exception => err
    errors << err.message
  end
end

if errors.banck?
  flash[:success] = "Imported with successful"
else
  flash[:error] = errors.join(", ")
end
redirect_to "/file"
```

**View**

```
<%= form_tag import_path, method: :post do %>
 <div class="input-group no-border">
  <%= file_field_tag 'file' %>
  <%= button_tag 'submit'%>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

o programa trava na linha "File.open(file).each do |line|"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu formulário precisa ter o atributo `enctype` definido como `multipart/form-data`. Como não está com esse atributo, o que você está a receber é somente o nome do arquivo, com esse atributo você poderá fazer:

```rb
file_content = params['file'].read
```

Dessa forma você terá o conteúdo do arquivo em `file_content`.

Comment: Show, havia esquecido do multipart. Sobre o método read, ele estava gerando outro erro, pois transformava tudo em string e estava passando o arquivo todo como um nome ou algo assim... Após trocar o .read para .path ele passou o caminho!

Comment: Que bom! No caso do `read`, eu quis dizer que no lugar de `File.open(file)` você pode chamar `params['file'].read`.

Comment: Ah, tá! Fica show